# Thick particle board sitting under heavy furniture

Tags: particle-board

How well does particle board hold up to concentrated pressure? I may be bringing a heavy (2-300+ lbs) chest into my apartment, and to protect my floor, I plan to sit it on some 1-1/4" particle board I happen to have (I'm pretty sure it's not MDF -- see picture). All of the weight will be concentrated into 4 narrow legs, and my concern is how well the board will stand up over time. Moisture won't be a problem, just the weight of the chest. (I'm also looking into my floor's load capacity, but for this question assume it's not an issue.) Thanks!

Edit: I already have the particle board, and it's 1 large-ish piece that's approximately the size of the entire chest, not separate pieces. I'd basically be putting the chest on a platform that would distribute the weight from the chest's 4 legs across its entire area.

[image]

Comment: Particle board is soft. Perhaps try some hardboard?

Comment: Does this chest have feet, or does it rest flat?

Answer (score 1):

If absolutely no moisture involved it will hold its shape.

Otherwise it will deform.

Properly designed and build floor can carry about 30-50 pounds per square foot.

Comment: Agree mostly, except to say that typical live load rating for residential floors is 40-50 pounds per square foot. (Dead load is lower.)

Answer (score 1):

It really does not matter how hard the board is. Your idea is to sacrifice the board to save the floor. Just make sure to make the squares under the legs large enough to distribute the weight. Also, why not just use moving casters, eg https://www.harborfreight.com/carpeted-floor-magic-moving-sliders-8-piece-57924.html ?